# Vue:These depedecies were not found

Tags: vue.js, vuex

98% after emitting CopyPlugin

ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors

These dependencies were not found:

- vue-material in ./src/main.js
- vue-material/dist/components in ./src/main.js
- vuex in ./src/store/store.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save vue-material vue-material/dist/components vuex

anybody face such issue before , i deleted my node modules ,  reinstall them still getting same issue

Comment: Hi, are "vue-material" and "vuex" referenced in your package.json as dependencies?

Comment: yes they are here is my dependencies         "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "core-js": "^3.4.4",
        "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",
        "vue-easy-lightbox": "^0.12.1",
        "vue-firestore": "^0.3.30",
        "vue-material": "^1.0.0-beta-13",
        "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
        "vuex": "^3.4.0"
    },

Comment: Can you push your code to github and post link here? So I can reproduce and have a look?